# calculating z-scores on long-format summary scores

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data from a web-based behavioural experiment that has trial-by-trial data and also cols with overall scores for two tasks in long format. Each entry in `task_1` and `task_2` is the overall score for one participant.

```
   id task_1   task_2
1 01    7       3
2 01    7       3
3 01    7       3
4 02    4       5
5 02    4       5
6 02    4       5
```

I am trying to use `mutate()` to add columns for

- z-scores for tasks 1 and 2
- factors based on a cut of the z-score

I'm having difficulty working with the repeated values down the `task` columns. Despite the repeated values, each participant has only one summary score for each task.

I've tried various chains of `group_by(id)`, `distinct()` and `mutate()` but this obviously creates a new data frame where theres is only one row per `id`, and then I'm stuck on how to mutate the z-scores and factor based on cuts back to the main df where there are multiple rows for each participant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you want to do some operations on unique records, and then merge those back into long format.

```
library(dplyr)
# Create example data
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                 task_1 = c(7,7,7,4,4,4,1,1,1),
                 task_2 = c(3,3,3,5,5,5,1,1,1))
# Remove duplicated rows
dfcalc <- df[!duplicated(df),]

# Do some operation and bind back to id cols
dfcalc <- cbind(dfcalc[,1], scale(dfcalc[,2:3]))
dfcalc <- as.data.frame(dfcalc)
colnames(dfcalc) <- c("id", "task1z", "Task2z")

# Merge back into original data frame with inner join
df <- inner_join(df, dfcalc, by="id")
df
```

First create a non-duplicated version, then run the calculations. Here I've used the scale function on col 2 and 3 and then used cbind to re-attach the id columns. Cleaned up the names, and then joined them back to the original df with an inner join.

If that isn't what you are expecting please post some example data with dput() and more complete code, and also show which output you were expecting so it is easier to assist with your question.

Comment: You've understood correctly, I had some code that effectively did this but I couldn't figure out the joint at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you are trying to achieve. If I parse out what you stated, it seems you are looking to do the following, but this doesn't make much sense to me:

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble(~id, ~task_1,   ~task_2,
01,    7,       3,
01,    7,       3,
01,    7,       3,
02,    4,       5,
02,    4,       5,
02,    4,       5)

library(dplyr)

df1 |> 
  add_count(id, task_1, task_2) |> 
  distinct() |> 
  mutate(across(c(task_1, task_2), function (x) (mean(x) - x) / sd(x), .names = "z_{.col}"),
         across(starts_with("z"), function(x) x > 0, .names = "test_{.col}")) |> 
  uncount(n)

# A tibble: 6 × 7
     id task_1 task_2 z_task_1 z_task_2 test_z_task_1 test_z_task_2
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <lgl>         <lgl>        
1     1      7      3   -0.707    0.707 FALSE         TRUE         
2     1      7      3   -0.707    0.707 FALSE         TRUE         
3     1      7      3   -0.707    0.707 FALSE         TRUE         
4     2      4      5    0.707   -0.707 TRUE          FALSE        
5     2      4      5    0.707   -0.707 TRUE          FALSE        
6     2      4      5    0.707   -0.707 TRUE          FALSE
```

Comment: This is close, except as far as I can see the z-score calculation doesn't account for the fact that the overall task score is repeated in all rows of the data for a given participant. e.g. for the column task_1, the z-scores in your answer are for the observations c(7,7,7,4,4,4) rather than c(7,4).

Comment: Revised answer.